# Cannot run new instance of async task at android 4.2

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have code, which perfectly runs on android 2.3.3, but doesn't run on android 4.2. When activity is starting, it should call instance of `Initialize` class which extends `AsyncTask`. But, at first activity start - it works, when I go to other activity and back - `progress` spinner is rotating and nothing happens, even exception isn't throwing.

I tried to debug this, it go to calling of `execute()` of new instance of Initialize and doesn't go inside `doInBackground()` of `Initialize`

Is this a problem only with android 4.2 or problem in other?

```
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (orders != null) {
            try {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new Initialize().execute();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.d("Error","exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```

Initialize

```
private class Initialize extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                if (orders == null || orders.isEmpty()) {
                    orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
                    BaseProcess Proc = new BaseProcess(MainActivity.this);
                    orders.addAll(Proc.getOrdersFromBase());
                    Proc.database.close();
                    Proc.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                 Log.d("Error","exception " + ex.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            update();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post your AsyncTask plz.

Comment: Are you using any other `AsyncTask`s besides this one? Bear in mind that `execute()` serializes your tasks by default on Android 3.2+ if your `targetSdkVersion` is 13 or higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, there are others AsyncTasks, what should I do? only run one AsyncTask at time?

Comment: AsyncTasks are for small tasks that don't take too much time. If your tasks takes too much time, use Threads instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are others AsyncTasks, what should I do?

First, only use `AsyncTask` for fairly short bits of work. `AsyncTask` is not suitable for where the work may take an indefinite amount of time (e.g., listening on a socket for incoming chat messages for a chat app).

Beyond that, [use `executeOnExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)) on API Level 11+ to opt into [the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR), which is the default behavior for `execute()` between API levels 4 and 10.